# S3 Last modified date in milliseconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get Last modified date in milliseconds for a S3 file.

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timezone

today = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='<REGION>')
objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket='<BUCKET_NAME>')

for o in objects["Contents"]:
     print(o["Key"] +" "+ str(o["LastModified"]))
```

From the above code I am able to get Last Modified time till seconds, is there a way to get it till milliseconds ?

Comment: Multiply it by 1000. AWS does not provide exact ms values.

Answer (score 0):

I think S3 does not keep milliseconds in header. You can explicitly cast to string with milliseconds but there will be zeroes.